# chrome extension webRequest onBeforeRequest ( details.requestBody = error: "Unknown error." )

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

When using the `webRequest` perms with the `onBeforeRequest` lifecycle method and the `requestBody` for the `optextraInfoSpec` as provided below I log the details variable for only POST request. the `detail.requestBody` is sometimes logs correctly in the console however majority of times is provides an error object `{ error: "Unknown error."}`. When I check the network tab for that same request does indeed have a `requestBody` however is not shows as a part of the details attributes.

event.js: (Background script)

```
const networkFilters = {
     urls: [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "*://*/*",
        "<all_urls>",
      ]
    };

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener((details) => {
      if(details.method=="POST") {
        console.log(details);
      }    
    },networkFilters,['requestBody']);
```

manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "storage",
    "alarms",
    "notifications"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "css": [],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

To replicate:

1. git clone https://github.com/shivamsinha15/clicker-key
2. npm install && npm start
3. goto chrome extensions: chrome://extensions/ and switch on "developer mode"
4. Click "Load unpacked" and open the background page
5. open a new tab e.g. www.twitter.com
6. observe how some console logs have requestBody = { error: "Unknown error."}

Comment: It's either intended or a bug. You can clarify it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Added issue here as well https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=930685